# How to add two arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

This an example code, I want to add the elements of the two arrays. I have imported NumPy and do not want to import array.

```
from numpy import *

a = array([])
b = array([])
c = array([])

d = input("Enter the length of the arrays")
print ("Enter the elements of array 1")
for i in range(d):
    append(a, int(input("Enter the element ")))
print ("Enter the elements of array 2")
for i in range(d):
    append(b, int(input("Enter the element ")))

for i in range(1, d+1):
    append(c, (a[i] + b[i]))

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Expected output should be sum of the elements of the array, but instead I get the following error:

> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: shouldn't the range go from 0 to d?

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but I think it could be useful: Given how you use `a`, `b` and `c` you probably should use a `list` here instead of a  `numpy.array`. arrays are fixed sized so `numpy.append` has to copy the complete array while lists are variable sized and `list.append` rarely needs to copy the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `append` doesn't mutate the state of its parameters. Instead it returns array with element added.

So to add an element to array you need to: `a = append(a, 2)`

Also in NumPy you can use `add(a,b)` to sum two arrays.

If we apply all that to your example we get:

```py
from numpy import *

a = array([])
b = array([])
c = array([])

d = input("Enter the length of the arrays")
print ("Enter the elements of array 1")
for i in range(d):
    a = append(a, int(input("Enter the element ")))
print ("Enter the elements of array 2")
for i in range(d):
    b = append(b, int(input("Enter the element ")))

c = add(a, b)

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Comment: just out of curiosity if I want to use the for loop and not the inbult add() function then what should i do ? @dmigo

Comment: You should go with `for i in range(d): c = append(c, (a[i] + b[i]))`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to convert `d` to `int` :

```
d = int(input("Enter the length of the arrays"))
```

After that you should assign the result of `append` function to the `array` :

```
print ("Enter the elements of array 1")
for i in range(d):
    a = append(a, int(input("Enter the element ")))
print ("Enter the elements of array 2")
for i in range(d):
    b = append(b, int(input("Enter the element ")))
```

then the result would be alright